# Custom fields setup when category selected filter subcategories

Tags: categories

Hi all I have custom taxonomies and custom user input fields for submiting their classifieds.
So what I was intending to do is: users should select category, I want to make it able when user select a category to show him in next select box field subcategories of that category.

So, if user select, car model>audi to automaticly open below select field is that audi> a3, a4, a5 or other.

I hope I was explained that pretty well.

Here is my custom field "category.php"

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb,$post;
    wp_reset_query();
    $template_post_type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'submit_post_type',true);
    $custom_post_types_args = array();  
        $custom_post_types = get_post_types($custom_post_types_args,'objects');

        global $post;

        foreach ($custom_post_types as $content_type){

            if($content_type->name == $template_post_type)
            {
                $taxonomy =  $content_type->slugs[0];
                if($content_type->name =='post' || strtolower($content_type->name) ==strtolower('posts')){ 
                    $taxonomy='category';
                }
            }
        }
    $catinfo = templ_get_parent_categories($taxonomy);
    if(count($catinfo) == 0)
    {
        echo '<span style="font-size:12px; color:red;">'.sprintf(__('You have not created any category for %s post type.So, this listing will be submited as uncategorized.',DOMAIN),$template_post_type).'</span>';
    }
    global $cat_array;
    $total_cp_price = 0;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['backandedit']) != '' || (isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid']!="") ){
        $place_cat_arr = $cat_array;
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=0; $i < count($cat_array); $i++){
            $place_cat_arr[] = @$cat_array[$i]->term_taxonomy_id;
        }
    }
    $cat_display = "";
    $tmpdata = get_option('templatic_settings');
    if(isset($tmpdata['templatic-category_type']) && $tmpdata['templatic-category_type'] != "")
     {
        $cat_display = $tmpdata['templatic-category_type'];
     }
    if(!$cat_display)
      {
        $cat_display = 'checkbox';
      }
    /* Start of checkbox */
    if($cat_display == 'checkbox')
    {
        if($catinfo) {
            if($cat_display==''){ $cat_display='checkbox'; }
            $counter = 0;
            if(is_active_addons('monetization')){ 
                global $monetization;
                $total_price = $monetization->templ_total_price($taxonomy);
                $onclick = "onclick=displaychk();templ_all_categories($total_price);";
            }else{ $onclick = "onclick=displaychk()";}
            ?>
              <div class="cf_checkbox">
            <div class="form_cat" >
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" id="selectall"  <?php echo $onclick; ?> /><?php _e('Select All',DOMAIN);?></label></div>
            <?php
            foreach($catinfo as $catinfo_obj)
            {
                $counter++;
                $termid = $catinfo_obj->term_taxonomy_id;
                $term_tax_id = $catinfo_obj->term_id;
                $name = $catinfo_obj->name;
                $cp = trim($catinfo_obj->term_price);
                if(!isset($cp) || $cp==''){ $cp = 0; }      
                $cat_term = explode(',',@$_REQUEST['category']);
                if(is_active_addons('monetization') && $cp !='0') { $dispay_price = " (".fetch_currency_with_position($cp).")"; }else{ $dispay_price = ''; } /* cat price works only with monetization */ ?>
                <div class="form_cat">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category_<?php echo $counter; ?>" value="<?php echo $term_tax_id.",".$cp ; ?>" class="checkbox" <?php if(isset($place_cat_arr) && in_array($term_tax_id,$place_cat_arr)){ echo 'checked=checked'; }?> onclick="fetch_packages('<?php echo $term_tax_id; ?>',this.form,'<?php echo $cp; ?>');"/>&nbsp;<?php echo $name.$dispay_price; ?>&nbsp;
                    </label>
                 </div>     
                <?php
                 $child = templ_get_child_categories($taxonomy,$term_tax_id); /* $termid = parent id */
                 $parent_id = $termid;           
                 $i=1;
                 $tmp_term_id=$term_tax_id;
                 foreach($child as $term)
                 {          
                    if($term){
                    $child_termid = $term->term_taxonomy_id;
                    $term_tax_id = $term->term_id;
                    $name = $term->name;
                    $child_cp = $term->term_price; 
                    if(!$child_cp){ $child_cp =0; }
                    if(is_active_addons('monetization') && $child_cp!='0') { $dispay_cprice = " (".fetch_currency_with_position($child_cp).")"; }else{ $dispay_cprice =''; } /* cat price works only with monetization */
                    if($term->category_parent!=$parent_id)
                    {   $i++;   $parent_id = $term->category_parent; }  
                    if($term->category_parent!=0):
                $p=$i*17;                               
                        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;-', $p);                       
                        if($tmp_term_id==$term->category_parent)
                        {
                            $i=1;
                            $p=$i*17;   
                            $i++;
                            $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;-', $p);   
                        }
                 ?>
                    <div class="form_cat" style="margin-left:<?php echo $p; ?>px;">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category_<?php echo $counter; ?>" value="<?php if($child_cp != ""){ echo $term_tax_id.",".$child_cp; }else{ echo $term_tax_id.",".'0'; }?>" class="checkbox" <?php if(isset($place_cat_arr) && in_array($term_tax_id,$place_cat_arr)){echo 'checked="checked"'; }?>  onclick="fetch_packages('<?php echo $child_cp; ?>',this.form)"/>&nbsp;<?php if(@$child_cp != ""){ echo $name.$dispay_cprice; }else{ echo $name.$dispay_cprice; } ?>&nbsp;</label></div>
                <?php endif; }
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';// finish cf_checkbox div
        }
    }
    /* End of checkbox */
    /* Start of selectbox */
    if($cat_display=='select' || $cat_display=='multiselectbox')
    { 
        $args = array('hierarchical' => true ,'hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'term_group');
        $terms = templ_get_parent_categories($taxonomy);

        if($terms) :
            if(is_active_addons('monetization')):
                if($cat_display=='select'):
                    $fetch_pkg = "onchange=fetch_packages(this.value,this.form);"; /* FUNCTION FOR FETCH PACKAGES */
                else:
                    $fetch_pkg = "onclick=fetch_packages(this.value,this.form);"; /* FUNCTION FOR FETCH PACKAGES */
                endif;
            else:
                $fetch_pkg = '';
            endif;

            if($cat_display == 'multiselectbox'){ $multiple =  "multiple=multiple"; }else{ $multiple=''; } /* multi select box */
            $output .= '<select name="category[]" id="select_category" '.$fetch_pkg.' '.$multiple.'>';

            $output .= '<option value="">'.__('Select Category',DOMAIN).'</option>';
            foreach($terms as $term){   
                $term_id = $term->term_id;
                $scp = $term->term_price;
                if($scp == ""){
                    $scp = 0 ;
                }
                /* price will display only when monetization is activated */
                if(is_active_addons('monetization') && $scp!='0') { $sdisplay_price = " (".fetch_currency_with_position($scp).")"; }else{ $sdisplay_price =''; }
                $term_name = $term->name;
                if(isset($place_cat_arr) && in_array($term_id,$place_cat_arr)){ $selected = 'selected=selected'; }else{ $selected='';} /* category must be selected when gobackand edit /Edit/Renew */
                $output .= '<option value='.$term_id.','.$scp.' '.$selected.'>'.$term_name.$sdisplay_price.'</option>';

                $child_terms = templ_get_child_categories($taxonomy,$term_id);      /* get child categories term_id = parent id*/                   
                $i=1;
                $parent_id = $term_id;
                $tmp_term_id=$term_id;
                foreach($child_terms as $child_term){ 
                    $child_term_id = $child_term->term_id;
                    $child_cp = $child_term->term_price;
                    if($child_term->category_parent!=$parent_id)
                    {   $i++;   $parent_id=$child_term->category_parent; }  
                    if($child_term->category_parent!=0):
                $p=$i*2;                                
                        $pad = str_repeat('-', $p); 
                        if($tmp_term_id==$child_term->category_parent)
                        {
                            $i=1;
                            $p=$i*2;    
                            $i++;
                            $pad = str_repeat('-', $p); 
                        }
                        /* price will display only when monetization is activated */
                        if(is_active_addons('monetization') && $child_cp!='0' ) { $cdisplay_price = " (".fetch_currency_with_position($child_cp).")"; }else{ $cdisplay_price =''; }
                        $term_name = $child_term->name;
                        if(isset($place_cat_arr) && in_array($child_term_id,$place_cat_arr)){ $cselected = 'selected=selected'; }else{ $cselected='';} /* category must be selected when gobackand edit /Edit/Renew */
                        $pad = str_repeat('-', $p); 

                        $output .= '<option value='.$child_term_id.','.$child_cp.' '.$cselected.'>'.$pad.$term_name.$cdisplay_price.'</option>';                                        
                    endif;
                } //child category foreach loop
            }
            $output .= '</select>';
        echo $output;
        endif;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displaychk(){
        dml=document.forms['submit_form'];
        chk = document.getElementsByName('category[]');
        len = chk.length;
        if(document.submit_form.selectall.checked == true) {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            chk[i].checked = true ;
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            chk[i].checked = false ;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do not only say what you want to do, but show what you have tried to do so, see [ask].

Comment: Sorry I am new here, I will try to summarize what have I done to get what I have now and what I tried to get what I want.

Comment: Not a problem, if possible show the code you're working with.

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: An additional hint, explain specific which part isn't working. It increases your chances of getting help.

Comment: Script above is fully working, but I wish to make it to show subcategory of parent category when user selects parent category. At this moment it shows both, parent categories and subcategories, I wish to separate them in two select boxes from which one will be with only parent categories, other empty until parent category is selected, and then will be filled with subacategories of that parent category. Sorry for bothering.